# Update model with response from an API after submitting form that uses nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

Forgive me if this has been answered. I spent a few hours searching for the answer to this both here and on Google.

I'm just getting started with Ruby on Rails. I'm trying to update a model with data from an API response after saving the data originally submitted via the form to two different models.

So basically I have a User model and a Character model. The sign up form collects data on the user and their character. In order to make an API request I have to at least get a few details about the character to pass in as part of the requested attributes (i.e. name, realm).

So I'm using a form_for with nested attributes:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :username %>
      <%= f.text_field :username %>

      <%= f.label :first_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name %>

      <%= f.label :last_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.fields_for :characters do |builder| %>

        <%= builder.label :realm %>
        <%= builder.text_field :realm %>

        <%= builder.label :name %>
        <%= builder.text_field :name %>

      <% end %>

      <%= f.submit "Sign Up" %>
<% end %>
```

This successfully submits all of the user info submitted to the User model and the realm and name submitted to the Character model. No problems there. However, I have several more fields that I want t fill in for the Character records just created from the API that provides all of the character info. What is the most efficient way to do this so that after the form submits, it updates the record (or adds data prior to save the record) with the data coming back from the API.

I don't need help on the specific fields and data returned. I have that all working, I'm just looking for a way to make the API request and complete the record with all data immediately after the form submits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest to use callback (:after_create) .

Depending upon the API processing you can choose between them .
:after_save
:before_save
:before_create

With any callback just get the data from your API and fill other character info's.

Hope that helps . Good luck .

Comment: Okay, I'll try that (:before_save). Do I implement this in the parent model? Also how do I access the nested form data to use in the callback function?

Comment: yeah, you can implement this in parent model and create child with association feature of rails. 
Take a look for brief : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks Vik! I was able to get it all figured out using a callback (after_save) to update the record using the .last method. That link you gave me was very informative as well. It's exactly what I was looking for as far as the associations go.